# Bootstrap-vue modal: Always Deleting the Last ID

Tags: mysql, node.js, vue.js, axios

I have a jobs page in my app where I am trying to delete the job by using its ID every time I try to delete the Job it is deleting the last id in the list it is not deleting the id which is selected here I am using REST API to perform the delete operation I also checked the ID when it is deleting by printing it to console even though I clicked the first Id in my list it is displaying the last id while it is deleting.

this is the job details page

```
<template>
 <div>
    <h2 class="mb-4 font-weight-light">Job Postings</h2>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <b-input-group class="w-30">
        <b-form-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Type to Search" />
        <b-input-group-append>
          <b-btn :disabled="!filter" @click="filter = ''">Clear</b-btn>
        </b-input-group-append>
      </b-input-group>
      <b-button variant="primary" class="d-flex align-items-center" v-b-modal.addJob><i class="material-icons mr-1"></i> Add Job</b-button>
    </div>
    <b-table responsive hover :items="jobs" :fields="fields" :filter="filter" no-sort-reset sort-by="postedOn" :sort-desc="true" class="mt-3 f6">
        <template slot="job_postingURL" slot-scope="data">
          <a class ="pink darken-3" :href="`${data.value}`" target="_blank">{{ data.value }}</a>   
        </template>
       <template slot="modify" slot-scope="row">
       <div slot="modal-footer" class="w-100">
        <div class="" > 
            <div>
              <b-button @click="showModal" variant="danger">Delete</b-button>
              <b-modal ref="myModalRef" hide-footer hide-header>
              <div>
                  <h3 class="font-weight-light">Do you want to delete this job?</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="float-right pt-4">
                <b-btn type="submit" variant="outline-danger"  @click="deleteJob(row.item.ID)">Delete</b-btn> 
             </div>
             <div class="float-right pr-2 pt-4">
               <b-btn  type="submit" variant="outline-danger"  style="padding-left: 10px" @click="hideModal">Cancel</b-btn>
             </div>
              </b-modal>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </template>
    </b-table>
    <add-job></add-job>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import AddJob from '@/components/jobs/AddJob'
import JobService from '../../services/JobService'
import axios from 'axios'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { orderBy } from 'lodash'
export default {
  components: {
    AddJob
  },
    data () {

        return {
            fields: [
              { Key: 'ID', label: 'ID', sortable: false},
              { key: 'job_title', label: 'Job title', sortable: true },
              { key: 'job_name', label: 'Company name', sortable: true },
              { key: 'job_location', label: 'Location', sortable: true },
              { key: 'job_postingURL', label: 'Job posting URL', sortable: false },
              { key: 'job_postingOn', label: 'Posted on', sortable: true},
              { key: 'job_postingBy', label: 'Posted by', sortable: true },
              { key: 'modify', sortable: true}
            ],
            filter: null,
            jobs: [
              {  
                  ID: this.ID,           
                  job_title: '',
                  job_name: '',
                  job_location: '',
                  job_postingURL: '',
                  job_postingOn: '',
                  job_postingBy: ''
              },
          ],
          active: false,
      value: null,
        }
    },
    // this method is to get the data from database
   async created () {
    try {
      this.jobs = await JobService.getJobs();
    } catch(err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
  },
  computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['firstName', 'lastName'])
    }, 
  methods: {
    showModal() {
        this.$refs.myModalRef.show()
      },
     focusMyElement (e) {
      this.$refs.focusThis.focus()
    },

    hideModal () {
      this.$root.$emit('bv::hide::modal','myModal')
      this.$refs.myModalRef.hide()
    },
      deleteJob (ID) {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/jobs/${ID}`)
          .then((res) => {
            this.job_title = ''
            this.job_name = ''
            this.job_location = ''
            this.job_postingURL = ''
            this.job_postingOn = ''
            this.job_postingBy = ''
            this.getJobs()
          console.log(res)
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          })
      },
      onCancel () {
        this.value = 'Cancle'
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are generating multiple modals, one for each item in jobs, but with the same ref.

When you open the modal to confirm the delete the last one is used hence you approve the deletion of the last item.

You could create only one modal, outside of the loop and use ID as a param. When clicking the delete button set ID and you should be done.

Below is an updated code.

Changes from OP code:

- moved `b-modal` at the top of the template
- added `ID` as component data, it is gonna be used to communicate between delete buttons and the confirmation modal
- changed signature of `showModal` to receive the ID of the job you want to delete
- changed signature of `deleteJob` to use the ID from the component instance

---

```
<template>
 <!--moved modal at the top-->
 <b-modal ref="myModalRef" hide-footer hide-header>
   <div>
    <h3 class="font-weight-light">Do you want to delete this job?</h3>
   </div>
   <div class="float-right pt-4">
    <b-btn type="submit" variant="outline-danger"  @click="deleteJob">Delete</b-btn> 
   </div>
   <div class="float-right pr-2 pt-4">
    <b-btn  type="submit" variant="outline-danger"  style="padding-left: 10px" @click="hideModal">Cancel</b-btn>
    </div>
 </b-modal>

 <div>
    <h2 class="mb-4 font-weight-light">Job Postings</h2>
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
      <b-input-group class="w-30">
        <b-form-input v-model="filter" placeholder="Type to Search" />
        <b-input-group-append>
          <b-btn :disabled="!filter" @click="filter = ''">Clear</b-btn>
        </b-input-group-append>
      </b-input-group>
      <b-button variant="primary" class="d-flex align-items-center" v-b-modal.addJob><i class="material-icons mr-1"></i> Add Job</b-button>
    </div>
    <b-table responsive hover :items="jobs" :fields="fields" :filter="filter" no-sort-reset sort-by="postedOn" :sort-desc="true" class="mt-3 f6">
        <template slot="job_postingURL" slot-scope="data">
          <a class ="pink darken-3" :href="`${data.value}`" target="_blank">{{ data.value }}</a>   
        </template>
       <template slot="modify" slot-scope="row">
       <div slot="modal-footer" class="w-100">
        <div class="" > 
            <div>
              <b-button @click="showModal(row.item.ID)" variant="danger">Delete</b-button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
       </template>
    </b-table>
    <add-job></add-job>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import AddJob from '@/components/jobs/AddJob'
import JobService from '../../services/JobService'
import axios from 'axios'
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { orderBy } from 'lodash'
export default {
  components: {
    AddJob
  },
    data () {

        return {
            fields: [
              { Key: 'ID', label: 'ID', sortable: false},
              { key: 'job_title', label: 'Job title', sortable: true },
              { key: 'job_name', label: 'Company name', sortable: true },
              { key: 'job_location', label: 'Location', sortable: true },
              { key: 'job_postingURL', label: 'Job posting URL', sortable: false },
              { key: 'job_postingOn', label: 'Posted on', sortable: true},
              { key: 'job_postingBy', label: 'Posted by', sortable: true },
              { key: 'modify', sortable: true}
            ],
            filter: null,
            jobs: [
              {  
                  ID: this.ID,           
                  job_title: '',
                  job_name: '',
                  job_location: '',
                  job_postingURL: '',
                  job_postingOn: '',
                  job_postingBy: ''
              },
          ],
          active: false,
          value: null,
          ID: null
        }
    },
    // this method is to get the data from database
   async created () {
    try {
      this.jobs = await JobService.getJobs();
    } catch(err) {
      this.error = err.message;
    }
  },
  computed: {
        ...mapGetters(['firstName', 'lastName'])
    }, 
  methods: {
    // added id param to showModal
    showModal(id) {
        this.ID = id
        this.$refs.myModalRef.show()
      },
     focusMyElement (e) {
      this.$refs.focusThis.focus()
    },

    hideModal () {
      this.$root.$emit('bv::hide::modal','myModal')
      this.$refs.myModalRef.hide()
    },
      // delete job relies on ID being set before the call
      deleteJob () {
        axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/api/jobs/${this.ID}`)
          .then((res) => {
            this.job_title = ''
            this.job_name = ''
            this.job_location = ''
            this.job_postingURL = ''
            this.job_postingOn = ''
            this.job_postingBy = ''
            this.getJobs()
          console.log(res)
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
          })
      },
      onCancel () {
        this.value = 'Cancle'
      }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: oh ok I tried to display it by taking out of the loop but now it is showing all the modals at a time like if I have 3 jobs it is showing three delete buttons when I click on it so If I select 2nd one it is deleting the 2nd job but it is showing multiple buttons.